# Dreamweaver regex to match id's with YUI format

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I'm trying to match ids with the form: `id="yui_..."`
but can't get the regex right. I'm trying:

```
(yui)+
```

intending this to find the capture group one or more times. But this returns no results.

[image: Dreamweaver Find and Replace]

Can anyone help? I've read through various regex101's but can't seem to get this right, no matter what permutation of the regex I try.

Comment: Try `yui[^"]*`. Or `\sid="yui[^"]*"`

Comment: You probably need to match the complete id, not just the start. There is probably also no need for the capturing group, so you can drop it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `yui[^"]*` works great. Thank you. Do you want to post the answer, and maybe explain why my version doesn't work while yours does? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(yui)+`  regex matches one or more consecutive repetitions of `yui` substring. It will match `yuiyuiyuiyuiyuiyuiyui`, or `yuiyui`, or just `yui`.

You want to match `yui` followed with any chars but `"` chars.

Thus, you may use

```
yui[^"]*
```

`[^"]*` matches 0 or more consecutive chars other than double quotation marks.

If you want to add any more "exclusion" chars, add them to the [*negated character class*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
yui[^"']*
```

The `[^"']*` pattern will match any 0+ chars other than `"` and `'`.

Comment: Thanks again Wiktor :)